# Is there anything that has the function to validate RDF that the same as the xml schema to xml?

Tags: schema, validation, rdf, jena

Now I come up with some problems about RDF.  I have to check a RDF file whether it is valid.  Below is an example of my RDF file:

```
<skos:Concept rdf:about='loc:107'>
<skos:prefLabel>Neptune</skos:prefLabel>
<skos:altLabel>Shoemaker-Levy 9 Comet</skos:altLabel>
<skos:broader rdf:resource='loc:3'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:110'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:111'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:112'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:108'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:115'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:113'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:109'/>
<skos:narrower rdf:resource='loc:114'/>
</skos:Concept>
```

It is `skos` actually.  I use jena to parse it,and jena can check the errors of RDF properties, such as replacing the `rdf:about` with `rdf:abou` ,jena will throw an exception.  But if I replace `skos:broader` with `skos:broad` ,jena will say ok.
 What can I do if I want to ensure that all the entities and properties in this RDF file are valid?  Or to say,all the `skos:broader`  are spelt correctly, not in wrong spell like `skos:broad` 
,and all skos entities or properties should be embedded in `<skos:Concept></skos:Concept>`.
  In a word,is there anything can do the work that xml schema do for RDF?

Comment: I don't know of a tool that can do this, but I expect something exists. If not my company will build a free tool to do it. Sorry, that's not a very helpful reply, but it's not actually a very common question, and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jena's [Eyeball tool](http://jena.sourceforge.net/Eyeball/) for this.

Comment: I will try it!And I find that there is a tool——qSKOS ,which is a Ruby API.As I have not learn Ruby before ,and there is less documents about it,I don't know whether it can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try SPIN constraints:
http://spinrdf.org/spin.html#spin-constraints

There is also a data quality library with some common ones:
http://semwebquality.org/ontologies/dq-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Some SKOS validation tools that we use:

**Skosify:** validate and improve SKOS vocabularies http://demo.seco.tkk.fi/skosify/skosify
with the code at https://github.com/NatLibFi/Skosify

**SKOS testing tool:** Assess the quality of SKOS vocabularies http://labs.sparna.fr/skos-testing-tool/ with the code at https://github.com/sparna-git/skos-testing-tool

**IDLab Turtle Validator:** A simple validator http://ttl.summerofcode.be/
with the code at https://github.com/IDLabResearch/TurtleValidator

Also see:

- W3C RDF Validation Service https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/
- Various SKOS Validation tools https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/SKOS/Validation